# Python tkinter add scrollbar to a list of Labels, Buttons and Frames

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, scrollbar

I have got [5 Frames](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3R7Q.jpg).  Frame1 contains the "New Target"-Button. Frame2 and-3 contain a list of Labels. The number of labels depens on how many entries are in the database. Frame4 and -5 contain buttons. Is it possible to add a scrollbar? I tried a lot to add a scrollbar but it doesn´t work. 
Here is my code that doesn´t contain the scrollbar:

```
import tkinter as tk
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error
from datetime import datetime
import sys
import os


def ende():
    main.destroy()

def restart():
    main.destroy()

def delete(index):
    print(labels[index * 2]["text"])

    try:
        connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                                             database='databasename',
                                             user='user',
                                             password='password')
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        sql_Delete_query = """Delete from Targets where Titel = %s"""
        cursor.execute(sql_Delete_query, (labels[index * 2]["text"],))
        connection.commit()
        print("Row deleted successfully ")
    except mysql.connector.Error as error:
        print("Failed to delete row from table: {}".format(error))
    finally:
        if (connection.is_connected()):
            cursor.close()
            connection.close()
            print("MySQL connection is closed")

        # Restarts the programm
        python = sys.executable
        os.execl(python, python, *sys.argv)


main = tk.Tk()
# Window size
main.geometry("400x400")
main.resizable(0, 0)
main['bg'] = 'red'
# Window position
w = main.winfo_reqwidth()
h = main.winfo_reqheight()
ws = main.winfo_screenwidth()
hs = main.winfo_screenheight()
x = (ws / 2) - (w / 2)
y = (hs / 2) - (h / 2)
main.geometry('+%d+%d' % (x, y))

fr1 = tk.Frame(main, borderwidth=2, relief="solid", bg="#271ee3", width=400, height=50)
fr2 = tk.Frame(main, borderwidth=2, relief="solid", bg="#0d9467", width=130, height=650)
fr3 = tk.Frame(main, borderwidth=2, relief="solid", bg="#3e1854", width=130, height=650)
fr4 = tk.Frame(main, borderwidth=2, relief="solid", bg="#3e1854", width=70, height=650)
fr5 = tk.Frame(main, borderwidth=2, relief="solid", bg="#3e1854", width=70, height=650)

fr1.pack()
fr2.pack(side="left")
fr3.pack(side="left")
fr4.pack(side="left")
fr5.pack(side="left")

fr2.grid_propagate(False)
fr2.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

fr3.grid_propagate(False)
fr3.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

fr4.grid_propagate(False)
fr4.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

fr5.grid_propagate(False)
fr5.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

# Button

tb = tk.Button(fr1, text="New Target", width=46, height=2, command=ende)
tb.grid(row=0)


# All targets - empty
labels = []
buttons = []

# Get current date

current_date = datetime.strptime(datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')


# Load all targets
def load_target():
    try:
        connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                                             database='database',
                                             user='user',
                                             password='password')
        sql_select_Query = "select * from Targets"
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute(sql_select_Query)
        records = cursor.fetchall()
        print("Total number of rows in ArmbandDB is: ", cursor.rowcount)

        i = 0
        if cursor.rowcount > 0:
            for row in records:
                date = current_date - row[2]

                labels.append(tk.Label(fr2, text=row[1], pady=15))
                labels.append(tk.Label(fr3, text=date, pady=15))
                buttons.append(tk.Button(fr4, text="Restart", command=restart, pady=13))
                buttons.append(tk.Button(fr5, text="Delete", command=lambda i=i: delete(i), pady=13))

                i = i + 1
            k = 0
            for e in labels:
                labels[k].grid(row=k, column=0, sticky='we')
                k = k + 1
            n = 0
            for e in buttons:
                buttons[n].grid(row=n, column=0, sticky='we')
                n = n + 1

    except Error as e:
        print("Error reading data from MySQL table", e)
    finally:
        if (connection.is_connected()):
            connection.close()
            cursor.close()
            print("MySQL connection is closed")


load_target()

print("Anzahl der labels2: ", str(len(labels)))

main.mainloop()
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Does it throw an error? Does it scroll the wrong window? Does it cause the program to crash? Also, please try to reduce the code down to a [mcve].  For example, if the issue is with scrolling widgets, there's no need for any database code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that the goal of your `ScrollBar` is to sroll the content of one of your frames.
If so, in tkinter there are no containter like a `ScrollArea` or `ScrollPane` in other languages. So you must create it yourself by using a canvas.

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
frame_container=Frame(window)

canvas_container=Canvas(frame_container, height=100)
frame2=Frame(canvas_container)
myscrollbar=Scrollbar(frame_container,orient="vertical",command=canvas_container.yview) # will be visible if the frame2 is to to big for the canvas
canvas_container.create_window((0,0),window=frame2,anchor='nw')

for i in range(100):
    Label(frame2, text=i).pack() # your labels, entries, whatever you whant inside your frame

frame2.update() # update frame2 height so it's no longer 0 ( height is 0 when it has just been created )
canvas_container.configure(yscrollcommand=myscrollbar.set, scrollregion="0 0 0 %s" % frame2.winfo_height()) # the scrollregion mustbe the size of the frame inside it,
                                                                                                            #in this case "x=0 y=0 width=0 height=frame2height"
                                                                                                            #width 0 because we only scroll verticaly so don't mind about the width.

canvas_container.pack(side=LEFT)
myscrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill = Y)

frame_container.pack()
```